# vis.js nodes not settling in UI

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using vis.js to visualize my network.
The number of **nodes and edges** that are being passed to this library is approximately around **500 and 2000** respectively.

Earlier when my code would add nodes and edges, the browser would become unresponsive after processing 1000 edges. 
I have included the following parameters in the options.

```
options.layout.hierarchical = true;
options.edges.smooth = false;
options.layout = {improvedLayout : false};
```

With `options.layout = {improvedLayout : false}` being added, I am able to get the output on the screen. 
However the nodes are not settled and they seem to take time to adjust to the layout. Also the hierarchy is not clearly seen.

How can I correctly display all the nodes and edges in a hierarchical manner with vis.js? What are the additional parameters that I have to add?